# area between step-wise functions in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, area

I would like to draw the area between two step wise functions.

I have try  `geom_ribbon`, but I get the draw with interpolations rather than constant in intervals.

```
comb = data.frame(time=rexp(20),n1=rep(1:10,each=2),n2=seq(from=2, to=11.5,by=0.5))
ggplot(comb) + geom_ribbon(aes(x=cumsum(time), ymin=n1, ymax=n2), fill="blue", alpha=.4) + geom_step(aes(x=cumsum(time), y=n1))+ geom_step(aes(x=cumsum(time), y=n2))
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you make this a minimally reproducible example by providing a few rows of the data?

Comment: Yes!, sorry for that. I just edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple fix is to move your `cumsum(time)` into your `comb` dataframe:

```
comb$ctime <- cumsum(comb$time)
```

then you can use `geom_rect()` as follows:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = ctime, xmax = lead(ctime), 
                ymin = n1, ymax = n2), 
            fill = "blue", alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_step(aes(x=ctime, y=n1))+ 
  geom_step(aes(x=ctime, y=n2))
```

Which yields:

[image]

Comment: That solves the problem. Thanks!. However, when I run it I get this warning message, do you know why?> ggplot(comb) + 

    Warning message: 
    Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_rect).

Comment: Sure, it's because the rectangle is defined by the four corners (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) and at the right hand side of the plot, xmin is `ctime`, but xmax is NA, since there's no next number in the series.